# 80's movie with evil amulet?

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was a movie or maybe TV show I remember seeing as a kid - probably in the 1980s, very late 1970s at the earliest. (The film/show itself could be older)

The detail I remember somewhat clearly is that there was an "amulet" which had some kind of evil influence or maybe mind controlling power. A male character who I think may have been the protagonist is particularly susceptible to this amulet.

At one point when he's not under the influence of the thing, he and a woman have met up - possibly having escaped some earlier danger. I think she has this amulet and shows it to him, which has a bad effect on him - possibly re-controlling him or maybe he reacts violently to try & get away from it.

To narrow it down a little - most likely this was shown on normal TV - ie it probably wasn't rated R or if it was, I suppose it might have been cut down somewhat. Also although it might have been a bit scary it was probably OK for a kid to watch.

Comment: You say 'amulet', which would usually be worn around the neck, but could it have been or more like a small figurine or statue the character carried around?

Comment: @LAK as far as I can recall, it was a very typical "large gem" looking amulet, whose secondary details (if any) I don't remember. I can't exclude that there could have been other objects in the story as you describe.

Comment: Thanks - then I think it's not "The Power" (https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081366/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_12), the statue isn't gemmed or large.

Comment: @LAK unfortunately I don't think so. Just watched the trailer for that one (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lq8hF0kYrlw). Also I just added to the q. that I don't think it was R rated.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Any details of any scenes you can remember? Character details, or clothing or general setting (gothic, turn of the century, modern, small town, city) or even music (synth vs organ vs orchestra) that can flesh it out more?

Comment: @MorrisonChang very little I'm afraid. I do think that the setting was in modern times, however. Not distant past nor a scifi future...

Comment: Baffled! (1972)? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zcv-qiGuL_w